# fgets for unknown string length

Tags: c, fgets

How can I read with `fgets` a string from keyboard buffer, of unknown length? `*fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`

Could I give `fgets` a `NULL` in the position of `int` size?

Answer (score 7):

No, you need to know what the line terminator is (newline and/or carriage return, typically), and keep reading in a loop until you get it. Of course, you also need to grow your buffer and copy each piece into it as you get them.

If you have it, POSIX' `getline()` does this.

Answer (score 3):

The length argument of `fgets` is one of the reasons the function is "better" than `gets`. You absolutely have to specify the amount of data the buffer you are passing can fit, otherwise your app may crash.

In most of my applications I simply use a buffer several times as long as it is required to fit whatever I expect to receive.

Using getline may cause a malloc/realloc, and if you have no problem with using dynamic memory feel free to use that function. I prefer simple `buffer[MAX_SIZE+1]` variables.

Comment: rare cases I use `getline()` function. It performs internal `alloc*()` calls and isn't portable. I prefer make `fgets()` until it returns NULL by using same memory in buf.